# PHP Laravel: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, fopen, permission-denied

I am trying to generate email but getting this error:

> fopen(/tmp/4701021fcbc23c3a52dde64ccca28857/body): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied

Relevant user/group have the permissions but its not working. I used lot of links but none is working.

We are running apache server on linux Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and using laravel framework.

Comment: Could you post the owners of the folder and further information about your specific version of framework, apache, etc?

Comment: laravel=5.2 apache=2.4.7

Comment: folder details are the most needed thing actually, can you tell me if it's a fresh installation? Did you use homestead?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637528 Jan 14 17:46 apache2*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6402 Jan  3  2014 apache2ctl*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     10 Jan 14 17:46 apachectl -> apache2ctl*

its a fresh installation and application is running fine but email feature generating error

Comment: What are the permissions of the contents in the `tmp` directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try running this commands in the console, is very important to execute them from your **project root directory**, if you don't it won't find the specific laravel commands:

1. `cd your_project_path`
2. `php artisan cache:clear`
3. `chmod -R 777 app`
4. `chmod -R 777 storage`
5. `composer dump-autoload`

I found a similar problem in the [laravel.io/forum](http://laravel.io/forum/05-08-2014-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied) with further information.

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "dump-autoload" is not defined.

Comment: @Irfi Yep sorry I fixed it, i don't know why but in latest version people is having trouble with artisan dump-autoload so try composers

Comment: at project root dir: i cant find this folder app/storage but in root dir i can find storage dir.

Comment: @Irfi I was not getting the point but I realised that my instruction was messed up and not clear

Comment: Asur, thanks for your efforts. Its already messed.!!! I am looking for more replys

Comment: @Irfi Ok hope you find a solution,if not you can always do a fresh start ;)

Comment: Okay this does not help me. I'm trying to run `php artisan typescript:transform` https://github.com/spatie/laravel-typescript-transformer

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write command below to grant your apache user needed privileges:

```
chown www-data -R storage
```

Regards dear

Answer (score 0):

Set up write permissions on `storage` directory inside your Laravel project directory:

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

Comment: same error "fopen(/tmp/c2516171047801e1b9c17509f81c0c24/body): failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Comment: Try to use same command with `/tmp` directiry and also try to clear cache: `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: running php artisan cache:clear  "Could not open input file: artisan"

Comment: Go to laravel project directory using `cd` command. Then run `chmod -R 777 storage` and `php artisan cache:clear`. If you'll do this from any another folder, `storage` directory will keep wrong permission and `artisan` will not be runned.

Comment: @Irfi, if my answer was helpful, please choose it as best answer.

Answer (score -2):

You need to access your Laravel project folder so you can run the following command

```
sudo chmod 777 -R 'your path to project'
```

Of course you have to replace 'your path to project' with the address of your project folder
for example /var/www/html/LaravelNiceProject
thats it

Comment: Running this command is dangerous. you're giving full access to your directory to the public.

Comment: Never `chmod 777` a directory unless you know what you're doing